# Electric flux density for a hollow cylinder using Gauss's law

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, gauss-law, magnetostatics

In the textbook of "Engineering Electromagnetics":

[image]
[image]

I understood it except the part highlighted with yellow(i.e. how did he find the charge distribution of the outer cylinder? What are the principles and laws that he used?. Can someone explain it for me in details, please?

Comment: I think you should put more effort on rephrasing your question and its context in your own words, instead of copying something directly from the textbook. It helps you understand your own question more and save people who try to help you a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The highlighted part is implying that the total charge on the inner surface of the outer cylinder is equal and opposite to the total charge on the outer surface of the  inner cylinder.

First, note that the two cylinders are both conductors. When there is an external field present, produced by the charge on the outer surface of the inner cylinder, electric field inside the outer conductor must be 0 because of electric equilibrium. Now image a Gaussian cylinder that goes inside the outer conducting cylinder. Because the flux goes from the charge on the inner cylinder to a negative charge on the outer cylinder and is symmetrical like the highlighted part mentioned, Gauss's law simplifies to $$E\cdot A={ Q }_{ enc }/{\epsilon}_{0}$$ Because E is 0 so  ${ Q }_{ enc }$ must be 0, therefore charge on the inner cylinder and charge on the inner surface of the outer cylinder is equal and opposite.

Comment: Ok, but I didn't understand why every line of electrical flux from the charge on the inner cylinder **_must_** terminate on a negative charge on the outer cylinder.

Comment: Because that is the direction of the electric field.